# How to set legacy_file_format in SQLite PDO?

Tags: sqlite, pdo

I need to make a new SQLite database with `legacy_file_format` on.  I'm told you turn it on via a `PRAGMA legacy_file_format = 1` to set the pragma on the database before you make it... but how can you do that before it's made?  I'm using PHP PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Pragmas like that need to be used between opening a brand new (file doesn't exist yet) database and the first table being created in it.

Note that the `legacy_file_format` pragma is becoming a no-op that has no effect in sqlite 3.31.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I guess that worked for setting the legacy_file_format flag, but not for the problem I was hoping to solve (my web host uses a different older version of SQLite, so my locally-developed web app doesn't work on the live site).

Comment: @DanGoodspeed The legacy file format is for versions of sqlite3 older than **3.3.0**. That version dates from from *2006*. Personally, I wouldn't feel comfortable using a release that old - there's been so many improvements and bug fixes to sqlite since then, to say nothing of whatever else it might be running of similar vintage.

Comment: My web host, which is typically great and up-to-date and knowledgeable, runs "cpanel server running centOS7, latest SQLite version supported is 3.7.17". And I just made a new Laravel 6 app that requires SQLite 3.8.8+.  And actually after my days of research into the problem made me realize some of the SQL queries I run in my app requires 3.21.  So now I'm desperately trying to find an inexpensive new web host for this small app that I spent months developing that should have gone live a week ago. *sigh*